# Select files between specified range with regex

Tags: regex, pyspark, filepath

I have a folder with 100 folders, named like:

```
parent_folder/05/01/
parent_folder/05/02/
parent_folder/05/03/
parent_folder/05/04/
...
parent_folder/05/29/
parent_folder/05/30/
```

How can I specify a path, with regex, that would select only the contents of folders `01 to 10`, then `11 to 20` and, finally, `21 to 30` ?

I am trying

```
"parent_folder/05/[1-10]*/*"
```

but it also selects 11, 12, ... all the way to 19.

**EDIT**: I want to read a large dataset in **pyspark** by 10-day intervals, and all suggested answers, so far, seem to fail.

Comment: When you say "select," what do you need to do with these paths? Do the selected paths need to be passed to another program?

Comment: I'm reading a huge database, and I want to read it by parts, in pyspark.

Comment: [1-10] doesn't work how you expect because regex doesn't treat the "10" as the number "ten".

Comment: What kind of regexes are you using? (perl, sed, grep, find) I think you should provide further information about what and how you want to achieve the selection.

Comment: Please try something like: `"parent_folder/05/"{01..10}`.

Comment: Are you trying to select the files from console to feed them to your program, or are you selecting them within you program. In other words, the intended use of the regex is from bash or python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the "10" to be grouped with your 01...09 set, you are going to use something like this:

`parent_folder\/05\/(0[1-9]|10)\/`

then, for your 10...20 set,

`parent_folder\/05\/(1[1-9]|20)\/`

and so on.

You can try these regexps with the following link : https://regex101.com/r/cXAYbS/2

In python, you are going to need:

`regex = r"parent_folder\/05\/(1[1-9]|20)\/"`

The link above has a "python" generator, where you can borrow some code:

https://regex101.com/r/cXAYbS/2/codegen?language=python

Comment: Hmm, Spark throws a : java.io.IOException: Illegal file pattern: Missing escaped character near index 1. And It does take regex in the file path.

Comment: Just adjust it to your regex flavour: `"parent_folder/05/(0[1-9]|10)*/*"`. It would help if you post your actual command.

Comment: I don't know much about bash with regex, but some parsers don't require you to escape `/`. Try this with all instances of \ removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
parent_folder/05/(?:0[1-9]|10)/
```

The '?:' is used for non-captering groups.

Comment: oh, I was late in my answer :)